# How to set a bool variable to true when a key is pushed and false when it is pushed again?

Tags: c#, boolean, hotkeys

I am having quite an issue in C# right now I am trying to code a function that detects when the F8 button is pushed and set the bool F8Pushed to true then when it is pushed again set F8Pushed to false.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
static bool IsKeyPressed() //This Function Returns True if F8 Is Pushed and False if F8 is up
{
    bool is_pressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(119) & 0x8000) != 0;
    return is_pressed;
}

static void CheckHotKey() //This is the Function that I am calling the other function from for debugging.
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsKeyPressed());
    }
}
```

Now the problem that I am having and cannot resolve is that I cant find a way to get the variable to copy its self to another variable and be able to go back to false if that makes sense. I can get a bool set to true if `IsKeyPressed() == true` however I cannot figure out how to get it back to false when it returns true again.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks for you help guys however I am still having some trouble heres an update.

```
static bool IsKeyPressed()
    {
        is_pressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(119) & 0x8000) != 0 && !is_pressed; 
        return is_pressed;
    }

    static void CheckHotKeys()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IsKeyPressed();
            if(is_pressed)
            {
                F8Pushed = true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(F8Pushed);
            if(IsKeyPressed())
            {
                F8Pushed = false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(F8Pushed);
        }
    }
```

I managed to get it to work kinda however it is very buggy and alot of times the key stroke doesnt detect any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you've written an infinite loop with your while(true). The variable will never change because the thread never gets out of this loop.

Comment: But i can call other function that can change it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. Your code contains so many problematic parts, that I choose to write a completely new code:

```
class Program
{
  const byte VK_F8 = 0x77;
  const byte VK_ESC = 0x1b;

  static bool globalAppState = false;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    bool lastState = IsKeyPressed(VK_F8);
    while (!IsKeyPressed(VK_ESC))
    {
      bool newState = IsKeyPressed(VK_F8);
      if (lastState != newState)
      {
        if (newState)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("F8: pressed");
          globalAppState = !globalAppState;
        }
        else
          Console.WriteLine("F8: released");
        lastState = newState;
      }
    }
  }

  static bool IsKeyPressed(byte keyCode)
  {
    return ((GetAsyncKeyState(keyCode) & 0x8000) != 0);
  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
}
```

Function `IsKeyPressed(VK_F8)` tells you always the current state (pressed/released) of the specified key.

When you need to do some action only on change *(from pressed to released, or from released to pressed)* replace the console output functions with your specific task.

*When you need some multi-threading like processing the event in a new thread, that is a different question... (outside of this scope)*

EDIT: Added change of variable on each new key pressed event. This is dirty solution...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make that variable `is_pressed` as global to keep current state. then make a Try like this:

```
static bool is_pressed;
static bool IsKeyPressed()
{
    is_pressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(119) & 0x8000) != 0 && !is_pressed;
    return is_pressed;
}
```

Where `&& !is_pressed` will toggles the value for you every time

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing the result of the key press in a boolean:

```
bool isKeyPressed = true;
```

You could then do this:

```
isKeyPressed == IsKeyPressed() && !isKeyPressed;
```